# Why Tesseract is not recognizing text properly?

Tags: python, image-processing, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I want to recognize text from the image I left below. I don't know the reason why the library recognizes some letters in the white space. I have already tried changing the config parameter.

This function I have coded returns this: `Legendary X yp`

Here is the code

```
def get_text(image, coord):
    im = Image.open(image)
    image_cropped = crop_text(im, coord)
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image_cropped, lang='eng', config='--psm 7')
    print(text)
    return text
```

The image from which I want to extract the text:

[image]

Comment: Is the shown image the result of the `crop_text` or is that the `image` input to `get_text`? In that case, the code and the `coord` would be needed, too. Refer to [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Without further (pre)processing, the following works on my machine:

```py
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

img = Image.open('mIjNm.png')
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config='--psm 6')
print(text.replace('\n', '').replace('\f', ''))
# Legendary X
```

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.19042-SP0
Python:        3.9.6
PyCharm:       2021.2
Pillow:        8.3.1
pytesseract:   5.0.0-alpha.20201127
----------------------------------------
```